# inserting data from 2 tables into new table i.e. table_out as below

Tags: mysql, join

---I have 2 tables--

table1:

```
venu_id | venu_code|  venu_capacity | venu_address|
--------------------------------------------------
     1  | 29       |    5           |  delhi      | 
     2  | 29       |    5           |  delhi      |   
     3  | 28       |    3           |  banglore   |
```

table2:

```
 application_id| can_name |  date      |fee_payment_status|can_name
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
        5516   |abhishek  |28‑OCT‑1990 |  success         |abhishek
        5517   |robin     |28‑OCT‑1990 |  success         |robin
        5518   |rohit     |28‑OCT‑1990 |  success         |rohit
```

I want to create a new table "table_out" which has columns

Application_id, can_name, venu_id, roll_number;

example

table_out:

```
id |Application_id| can_name | venu_id| roll_number
-------------------------------------------------- 
1  |     5516     |  abhishek| 29     | 290000001
2  |     5517     |  robin   | 29     | 290000002
3  |     5518     |  rohit   | 28     | 280000001
```

table_out connects with other tables using foreign keys and finally I want to read the data from the other 2 tables and insert it into table_out.

I want to generate roll_number which have 8 digits and starts with "venu_code" and roll_number partition by "venu_capacity" and  order by "venu_address".

Example:

| venu_id | venu_capacity | venu_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 5 | Delhi |

roll_number=55000001 and so on....
capacity reduce to 4 in delhi

Finally wants to insert all data from  other tables into table_out with roll_number  which is unique and sequential as above shown in example table_out

how to do it in mySql?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me please help... I want to implement it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using loop procedure or using a cursor we can do so but exactly I don't know how to do it... Please help